# rails missing FROM-clause entry for table (counting children)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a simple parent has_many children relationship and I'm trying to get all parents that have less than n children.

```
Parent.select("parents.id").joins(:children).group('parents.id').having('COUNT(children.id) < ?', n).reorder('parents.id')
```

The error that keeps appearing is:

```
SELECT parents.id FROM "parents" INNER JOIN "children" ON "children"."parent_id" = "parents"."id" GROUP BY parents.id HAVING count("children"."id") < 100
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "children"
```

From what I have read online, this should be working. I've searched through many posts with related questions, but none of the answers seem to relate. There is a scope on the parent-child relationship for ordering, and so that's why I'm reordering by parent id.

What is the "FROM-clause" entry that I need?

Running Rails 4.2 and Postgres

Comment: What happens if you run the raw *SQL* in *PgAdmin* or *psql*? Does it work or do you get the same error? Does the `children` table definitely have both `parent_id` and `id` columns?

Comment: same error in my psql. I confirmed that `children` does have `parent_id` and `id` columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that your `HAVING` clause references something -- `children.id` -- that isn't present in your `SELECT`. `HAVING` is evaluated after the `GROUP BY` and the `SELECT`, so I believe what it currently has available to it is just `parents.id`.

See the [`SELECT` doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) for more detail on that.

So, ultimately, you need to have the child id count available from the `SELECT` in order to then call `HAVING` on it.

One way that comes to mind to accomplish both of these things at once would be to use `count` as a *window function*.

The SQL would then look something to the effect of this:

```
SELECT parents.id, count(children.id) over(partition by children.id) as children_id_count
FROM "parents"
INNER JOIN "children" ON "children"."parent_id" = "parents"."id"
WHERE count(children.id) over(partition by children.id) < 100
GROUP BY parents.id
```

**Note:** The window function needs to be repeated in the `WHERE` clause since the alias has not yet been created at that point.

AFAIK, *Active Record* does not natively support *window functions*, so you'll need to use raw *SQL* for that.